# Logo above the navigation bar

Tags: html, css

Ok guys, since the first guys answer didnt work i added the whole code. Im sorry this is my first question on this site so dont get mad over my mistakes.

css:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>

html {
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background: #70bg32;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient( #fff, #7cceff);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient( #fff, #7cceff);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient( #fff, #7cceff);
    background: -o-linear-gradient( #fff, #7cceff);
    background: linear-gradient( #fff, #7cceff);
}

ul {
position: fixed;
   list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    overflow: hidden;
background-color: #31a7ff;
top:0;
width: 100%;
border: 1px solid #0060a7;
}

li {
float: left;

}

li a {

    display: block;
color:white;
text-align:center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration:none;

}


li a:hover {
    background-color: #15649f;
}


.active {
    background-color: #004376;
}

.headerLogo {
float:left;
margin:auto;
display:inline-block;
background:black;
padding:5px;
width:100%;
color:white;
}
.logo
{
width:32px;
height:32px;
}
```

html:

```
</head>
<body>

<img class="logo"
     src="amundlogo.png" />
<div class="headerLogo">
  <ul>
<li><a href=">#home">menybrah</a></li>
<li><a href=">#home">anothaone</a></li>
<li style="float:right"><a href=">#home">todaright</a></li>
</ul>

</div>

<h3>Linear Gradient - Diagonal</h3>
<p>This linear gradient starts at top left. It starts red, transitioning to yellow:</p>

<div id="grad1"></div>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions do not support gradients.<$

</body>
</html>
```

more words more words more words more words more words more words more words more words more words more words more words more words more words more words more words more words more words more words more words more words more words more words more words more words more words more words more words more words more words more words more words more words more words more words more words more words more words more words more words more words more words more words more words more words more words more words more words

Comment: Please add JSFiddle

Comment: I dont know what that is

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tcou4dk3/2/ (click link, add your HTML and CSS, and add that link to your post)

Comment: Don't use JS Fiddle for this. Stackoverflow [allows you to put live demos in your question](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: You need to provide a [MCVE]. "I cant get my logo above my navigation bar." is meaningless unless your code includes a navigation bar.

Comment: You've set three CSS properties, it doesn't make much sense to set any of them to the values you've given them if you set either of the other two to the values you've given them.

Answer (score -1):

put your logo above the navigation like this

```css
.header {
float:left;
margin:auto;
display:inline-block;
background:black;
padding:5px;
width:100%;
color:white;
}
.logo
{
width:32px;
height:32px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img class="logo"
     src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSN1_sXp8T6higZFr994Vr8QUmav0Lqw2XYTimUhflQcI_Lo3ojLFjOGfg" />
</div>

<div class="header">
  <h5>Navigation bar</h5>
</div>
```

Comment: "your logo is inside the navigation bar" — What makes you think that? There isn't a navigation bar in the code in the question.